# Как узнать id блока, в который перетащили элемент, и передать серверу?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, php, sortable, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть задача создания 3-4-х списков статусов выполнения сделки.

Делал простое перетаскивание, цепляет id перетаскиваемых блоков, выводится 1,2,3,4,5,6 и т.д.

Нужно, чтобы при перетаскивании из столбца 1 в столбец 2 или 3 скрипт присваивал каждому блоку id, id столбца, в котором этот блок оказывается, и передавал это обработчику примерно так: 1:2,3:1,3:3,2:6,2:5,2:4, где первое число - это id столбца, а второе - это id блока.

Начал делать, но не понял, как делать дальше: http://jsfiddle.net/ntran48t/2/

Помогите сделать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[В примере](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ntran48t/3/), гляньте в консоли - такой результат нужен?

```
// ...
var ids = [];
$(".connectedSortable").each(function(i, ul){
    ids[i] = $('li',ul).map(function(k, li){
        return i + ':' + $(li).data('statisid');
    }).get();
});
// ...
```

Comment: Небольшая поправка: id столбца должно брать из data-tid.
____

Сам справился, спасибо вам!

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, это уже на суть [не особо влияет][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ntran48t/4/